# optimizing the data structure implementation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is a stream of random characters coming like 'a''b''c''a'... and so on. At any given point in time when I query I need to get the first non repeating character. For example, for the input "abca", 'b' should be returned since a is repeated and the first non repeating character is 'b'.

There needs to be two methods, one for inserting and one for querying.

My solution is to have a linkedList to store the incoming stream characters. While I get the next character, I just compare with all the current characters and if present I will not insert into the end of linkedlist, else I will insert at the end. By this approach, the query will take O(1) since I will get the first element on the linkedlist and insert will take O(n) since I need to compare from the first element till the last element in the worst case.

Is there any better performing way?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by a better approach. There are always trade-offs, for example you can store your incoming characters both in a list and a hash table. You use the list to keep track of the order of characters and the hash table for checking whether a character has been encountered before. You've improved your time performance at the expense of space. Is that an improvement overall? It depends what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you haven't explained your algorithm well or it won't return the correct result. In the example `a b a`, would your algorithm return `a` (because it is the first element in the linked list)?

Anyway, here is a modification that improves performance. The idea is to use a hash map from characters to (doubly) linked list nodes. This map can be used to determine if a character has already been inserted and to get to the required node quickly. We should allow a `null` value for the map target (instead of the list node) to express a character that has ocurred more than once already.

The insertion method works as follows:

Check if the map contains the current character (*O(1)*). If not, add it to the end of the list and add a reference to the map (*O(1)*).

If the character is already in the map: Check if the pointed to node is `null` (*O(1)*). If so, just ignore it. If it is not, remove the pointed to node from the list and update the reference to a `null` value (*O(1)*).

Overall, a *O(1)* operation.

The query works as in your previous solution.

Here is a C# implementation. It's basically a 1:1 translation of the above explanation:

```cs
class StreamAnalyzer
{
    LinkedList<char> characterList = new LinkedList<char>();
    Dictionary<char, LinkedListNode<char>> characterMap 
        = new Dictionary<char, LinkedListNode<char>>();

    public void AddCharacter(char c)
    {
        LinkedListNode<char> referencedNode;
        if (characterMap.TryGetValue(c, out referencedNode))
        {
            if(referencedNode != null)
            {
                characterList.Remove(referencedNode);
                characterMap[c] = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var node = new LinkedListNode<char>(c);
            characterList.AddLast(node);
            characterMap.Add(c, node);
        }
    }

    public char? GetFirstNonRepeatingCharacter()
    {
        if (characterList.First == null)
            return null;
        else
            return characterList.First.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your solution with sample code?